Why does importing FastAPI TestClient into my PyCharm debugger session take 24 seconds?
Using PyCharm Pro, importing FastAPI TestClient takes 2 seconds in run mode and 23 in debug. I don't know if this is PyCharm, FastAPI, Starlette, or basically where I start to reduce the time.
Here is everything installed in the venv:
> uv pip list
Package           Version
----------------- --------
annotated-types   0.7.0
anyio             4.4.0
certifi           2024.6.2
click             8.1.7
colorama          0.4.6
dnspython         2.6.1
email-validator   2.2.0
fastapi           0.111.0
fastapi-cli       0.0.4
h11               0.14.0
httpcore          1.0.5
httptools         0.6.1
httpx             0.27.0
idna              3.7
iniconfig         2.0.0
jinja2            3.1.4
markdown-it-py    3.0.0
markupsafe        2.1.5
mdurl             0.1.2
orjson            3.10.5
packaging         24.1
pluggy            1.5.0
pydantic          2.7.4
pydantic-core     2.18.4
pygments          2.18.0
pytest            8.2.2
python-dotenv     1.0.1
python-multipart  0.0.9
pyyaml            6.0.1
rich              13.7.1
shellingham       1.5.4
sniffio           1.3.1
starlette         0.37.2
typer             0.12.3
typing-extensions 4.12.2
ujson             5.10.0
uvicorn           0.30.1
watchfiles        0.22.0
websockets        12.0

import time

START_TIME = time.time()
def test_debugger_speed():
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Time taken for test_debugger_speed: {end_time - START_TIME} seconds")


def test_debugger_speed_with_client():
    start_time = time.time()
    from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Time taken for importing TestClient: {end_time - start_time} seconds")


Run output:
C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1\.venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2024.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1\test_slow_debugger.py 
Testing started at 3:12 PM ...
Launching pytest with arguments C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1\test_slow_debugger.py --no-header --no-summary -q in C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1

============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_slow_debugger.py::test_debugger_speed PASSED                        [ 50%]Time taken for test_debugger_speed: 0.00400090217590332 seconds

test_slow_debugger.py::test_debugger_speed_with_client PASSED            [100%]Time taken for importing TestClient: 0.8693747520446777 seconds


============================== 2 passed in 0.90s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0

Debug output:
C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -X pycache_prefix=C:\Users\RYZEN\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2024.1\cpython-cache "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2024.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 1842 --file "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2024.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1\test_slow_debugger.py
Testing started at 3:12 PM ...
Connected to pydev debugger (build 241.17890.14)
Launching pytest with arguments C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1\test_slow_debugger.py --no-header --no-summary -q in C:\Users\RYZEN\prdev\pythonProject1

============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_slow_debugger.py::test_debugger_speed PASSED                        [ 50%]Time taken for test_debugger_speed: 0.019998788833618164 seconds

test_slow_debugger.py::test_debugger_speed_with_client PASSED            [100%]Time taken for importing TestClient: 24.218650102615356 seconds


============================= 2 passed in 24.30s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0



Actually, I wasn't be able to reproduce the issue despite the fact that I installed all dependencies your mention and used your code snippet. So, I would assume that the issue does not relate to FastAPI or Starlette. But one weird thing I noticed is that the importing TestClient from starlette from starlette.testclient import TestClient takes 2 times less time than importing this client from fastapi.

Thanks, good to know, but also kinda annoying because I guess it must be something with my system, Pycharm installation, or general gremlins... Can I ask what your actual timings were? Or mostly I just want the ratio of time to run vs time to debug... Fwiw I upgraded my ryzen 2600x to 5900x and it halved both the times, i can handle ten seconds (more like 19 with an actual Fastapi project rather than just the test client)

Yes, seems so..
Sure! Running test_debugger_speed_with_client took 0.26s, debugging the same took 0.81
